# Is non-integer power of a kernel still a kernel?

Tags: bayesian, gaussian-process, kernel-trick

When fitting a Gaussian process, we use a kernel function to define the covariance matrix. It is well known that if $k(x, y)$ is a kernel function, then $k_1(x, y) = k(x, y)^p$ is also a kernel function for any integer $p$. This is obviously just a result of induction from the fact that multiplication of two kernels is still a kernel.

Is this still true when $p$ is not integer, say $\frac{1}{2}$?

PS: This is motivated by the fact that the arithmetic mean of kernels is still kernels, but sometimes we may want geometric mean instead. If $p$ were allowed to be non-integer, then one could conclude that the weighted geometric mean of kernels is also a kernel, which is very useful in practice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have exactly defined the class of infinitely divisible kernels, i.e., a kernel $k(x, y)$ such that $k(x, y)^p$ is a kernel for any $p > 0$.

Not all kernels are infinitely divisible.  Many of the kernels you know and love are infinitely divisible.

Comment: Could you please add a reference for this topic?

Comment: This link should go directly to a freely downloadable paper https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjGu5_75Mz9AhWYK1kFHYmpDNgQFnoECAcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fprojecteuclid.org%2Fjournals%2Fpacific-journal-of-mathematics%2Fvolume-38%2Fissue-2%2FSchlicht-mappings-and-infinitely-divisible-kernels%2Fpjm%2F1102970054.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2t5zbon47aToW-SEaJJFkw